# Mediaplayer playing even after exiting app?

Tags: java, android, audio, time, media-player

I have the following code which plays some audio after some time in a service. The issue is, after exiting the app, the media player continues to run; I want to stop the audio from playing after the app has has been exited or closed.

**Here is my audio:**

[image]

**By the way, ten and three were declared at the top:**

```
 MediaPlayer ten;
MediaPlayer three;
```

I would really appreciate **any** feedback (positive or negative)! Thank you so much for all of your help, let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: have you called stopService() or stopSelf() before exiting application?

Comment: @Aakash No, only place I called stopService is in the onFinish(). Where else should I call it? Is there some method that always gets called when app is being exited?

Comment: according to code shown in image, it seems you are extending service class, you need to stop the  service in your onDestroy() of your activity or if you can make an application class and stop the service in the onDestroy() of that class, it will also be helpful, you will need to define the application class's name in the manifest in that case

Comment: @Aakash  For some reason even after stopping the service it still runs

Comment: also you need to stop media player

Comment: @Aakash how would I do that

Answer (score 0):

Option1 : You can use a foreground service so that your service runs only when the app is running.
See more about foreground services here.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Option2 : Stopping your service from onDestroy method in Activity. Using this code

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent in = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyService.class);
        stopService(in);
    }
```

Recommendation :
Also you should always try to use only one MediaPlayer object and do something like this :

```
stopPlaying(); // To stop whatever is currently playing
mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.second);
mp2.start();
```

In your case I would probably go with Option2.
All the Best :)

Comment: Hey, the problem with option two is that the user may exit the app from a **different** activity. Do I have to put that in every single activity's onDestroy method? I have 15 activities...

Comment: A simple copy paste of the onDestroy method from above should not take much time. Or maybe you could `return START_NOT_STICKY` from the onStartCommand() of your service. That seems a better option. Read more about it over here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY